# SSRS Pre filtering on account

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm having trouble with the pre-filtering on the account entity, I'm using crm2011 UR13 and I'm trying to run a basic report on the account entity, i tried this 2 queries:

```
select * from FilteredAccount as CRMAF_Account

select * from FilteredAccount as CRMAF_FilteredAccount
```

And no result, beside not filtering if you edit the filter the property is giving an error. I tried the same on the order but with just 1 query since i was being lazy:

```
select * from FilteredSalesOrder as CRMAF_FilteredSalesOrder
```

and this one worked fine at the first attempt.

Then I created a report on the account with the wizard, and i have the same error as I had with my custom reports.

Anyone knows if somethig went wrong during the rollup relese?
[image]
[image]

As I said is happening only on the account, and if there is the pre-filter. If i delete it the report runs without problems. As I mentioned is not working correctly even for Wizard - out of the box created reports on the Account entity.

Best Regards

Comment: Did this work before you installed UR13? If so, what Rollup were you on previously? Also, did you install the SRS extension rollup in addition to the CRM server rollup? Have you tried going ahead to rollup 15 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2843571) to see if that fixes the issue? Did you verify the filtering criteria (which defaults to Modified On in Last 30 Days) returns records in CRM?

Comment: Well i can't confirm that but someone should have noticed since we were on UR12 for 6 months. The pre filtering with CRMAF_ should set the filter on the id of the current record, but in the account instead of having the id of the account i have an error in that property. It's not possible to install new rollups. Is doing it only with the account. I want a confirm that is an actual problem with UR13 and not with our environment.

Comment: Well UR 13 has been out for a while and I haven't seen error reports on using Pre-Filtering - which is a very widely used piece of functionality. This is likely an environment or report setup issue. Can you rollback to UR 12 to confirm it works correctly in UR 12?

Comment: That's sadly not an option. The point is that for all the other entities is just working fine, is just the account that is complaining about the pre-filtering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when the ID field of the entity is not set to searchable = yes.

Navigate to the solution containing the entity (Settings -> Solutions, alternatively open the default solution via Settings -> Customizations -> Customize the System), open the fields subsection (in your case Account -> Fields). Find the field accountid and set the attribute searchable to Yes. Publish all customizations and it should work.

Best regards,
Markus